# Pandas df 'A' and 'B 1' are column name. How do I reference 'B 1' like df.A ?

Tags: python, pandas

The same question holds for column names such as 'C.1'...
Is there a short cut like `df.A` for column names 'B 1' and 'C 1' other than `df['B 1']` and `df['C.1']` ?

Comment: Do I get down voted because the answer to this was in the docs ?

Comment: I certainly didn't downvote, but this could be seen as a basic beginners/low effort question, so I can understand why you were downvoted.

Comment: It certainly is a beginner question... as for the low effort maybe the person should consider size of the world before making such judgments.

Comment: Each person is entitled to their opinion. Me, personally I think it is okay, because I also had such doubts and queries when I started learning pandas, so I don't mind answering these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the dot notation to access columns if the column name

- begins with a digit
- contains whitespace characters
- contains operator symbols and punctuation
- conflicts with an existing method name or attribute

The dot notation is similar to accessing object's attributes, and you must follow python's variable naming rules if you want to access them that way. For anything else, you'll have to use `[...]`.

For a more detailed view, view the note at the bottom of the [documentation](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#attribute-access).

Comment: Thank you.  What may be obvious for some may not be in another life.

Comment: no, just another tab that was not refreshed.  I validated twice.  Thank you again.