# Subsetting a dataframe based on row value, where the row value and column name is stored in a VARIABLE

Tags: python, pandas, variables, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([["fruit", 12341], ["vegetable", 45642]]))
df.columns = ['this','result']
```

This is what the dataframe may look like

```
     this        result
0    fruit       12341
1    vegetable   45642
```

'this' and 'result' are the column names.
Let's say one of the column names are stored as a string variable named 'var'

One of the row values 'fruit' in the column 'this' is stored as a key in the dictionary named 'dict'.

```
var = 'this'
dict = {'fruit': 'apple', 'vegetable': 'orange'}
```

I'm trying to perform some subsetting showed in the code below

```
for k, v in dict.items():
    print(k)
    print(type(k)) #<class 'str'>
    df = df[df.var == k]

df
```

I know already know

```
    df = df[df.this == 'fruit']
    df = df[df.this == 'vegetable']
```

But the row values and column names will be stored as string variables ONLY! Is there anyway, you can subset dataframes where row value and column names are **variables**

I'm not sure if this is even possible unless you guys know. I don't mind if a solution is posted using loc or iloc but I absolutely need to have row values and column names stored in **variables**.

I've tried something like using `eval` which prints the value in the variable but to no avail. I apologize in advance if I've asked something that's impossible to achieve.

**Expected output** will be an empty dataframe because `df = df[df.var == k]` is equivalent to `df = df[df.this == 'fruit']` and `df = df[df.this == 'vegetable']` when the code iterates through the dictionary whose keys are the only existing row values for the column name 'this'

Comment: can you add the expected output

Comment: The answer is yes... whatever it is your are trying to do, the answer is yes! ... Problem is, I can't figure out what you are trying to do.  Please provide something that shows us what you expect the results to look like.

Comment: Nothing is impossible in coding unless we understand the problem properly.

Comment: @Bharathshetty Added it. The idea I'm trying to accomplish is, use VARIABLES as row value and column name. Not to get the expected output.

Comment: Do not use `.` use indexing like `df[var_name]`. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861214/pandas-df-a-and-b-1-are-column-name-how-do-i-reference-b-1-like-df-a/46861240#46861240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead dot notation `[]` and insted name `dict` use `dict1`, `d` because `dict` is code word in python.

```
d = {'fruit': 'apple', 'vegetable': 'orange'}

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k)
    df = df[df[var] == k]
    print (df)

#first loop
fruit    
    this result
0  fruit  12341

#second loop
vegetable
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [this, result]
Index: []
```

But if in first iteration is output filtered by first key, so always second loop return empty dataframe, because output of first loop (filtered dataframe) is assigned to variable `df`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I understand OP question this is part of code (which is not in question) and your `.isin` is for filtering all `var` columns by all `keys`. So both answers have different output.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes I prefer to follow the "give OP what they need but don't know they do" rather than "give OP exactly what they ask for, even if it makes no sense". Sometimes it's better to do both! Cheers.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I think the best is create answer with desired output and explain, if  it should be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Use `isin`:

```
df = df[df[var].isin(dct.keys())]
```

This gets rid of the loop (well, it doesn't result in an empty dataframe, but why would you want an empty dataframe?).

Note that you cannot use the *dot* notation when referring to columns with variable names. You'll need to use `[...]` syntax. For more information on where you can, and cannot use the dot notation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46861240/4909087).

> You cannot use the dot notation to access columns if the column name
>
> - begins with a digit
> - contains whitespace characters
> - contains operator symbols and punctuation
> - conflicts with an existing method name or attribute
>
> The dot notation is similar to accessing object's attributes, and you
>   must follow python's variable naming rules if you want to access them
>   that way. For anything else, you'll have to use `[...]`.
>
> For a more detailed view, view the note at the bottom of the
>   [documentation](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#attribute-access).

Furthermore, don't use `dict` to name variables, that shadows the builtin `dict` class with the same name. Now you have used it, use `del dict` to get back dict functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as a comment, but not enough reputation for that.

I'd like to add two notes, besides the answers, which solve the problem pretty well.

Note 1: Do not use `dict` as a variable name, since it is a *builtin*.

Note 2: If you are using variables when accessing *df*, you might not be sure if the attribute is in *df*, therefore you can also use *builtin* function `getattr(df, var, None)`, where the *third* argument is what gets returned in case the *df* has no attribute *var*.